# Suppose that "f(x)→∞ as x→a" and "g(x)→c as x→a", where c<0. Prove that "[f(x)g(x)]→-∞ as x→a".

Tags: limits, proof-writing

Suppose that "$f(x)\to\infty $ as $x\to a$" and "$g(x)\to c$ as $x\to a$", where $c<0$. Prove that "$[f(x)g(x)]\to -\infty$ as $x\to a$".

I've already solve the case $f(x)+g(x)$ by using the $ε-δ$ definition, then I stuck.

Can somebody else help me to figure out?

Comment: $f(x)>\frac {2N} {-c}$ and $g(x) <\frac  c 2$ implies $f(x)g(x) <-N$.

Comment: I don't really sure am I really understand why g(x) < c/2, can you please check my opinion? Since c-ε < g(x) < c+ε for every ε > 0, especially, choose ε = -c/2, then we have g(x) < c/2.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.